# WooCommerce API: create order and checkout

Tags: android, wordpress, api, woocommerce, checkout

**WHAT AM I TRYING TO DO**

I want to make a **Native Android APP** (Not HTML5/Jquery mobile) for my Woocommerce website. I am trying to setup the APIs using [kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library).

So far I managed to retrieve the lists of products, coupons, customers, orders etc... which I could use to display in my Android app.

Now I want to replicate add to cart/checkout process in the android app, but it seems this library dosen't provide functions for such workflow.

**MY QUESTION**

How can I achieve the follwing workflow with REST APIs in my Android app?
(Similar to the website checkout process)

Flow:

1. Add to cart

[image]
[image]

2. View cart and update order

[image]

3. Check out and confirmation

[image]
[image]

Please tell me if I'm missing any API calls.

If someone already achieved this, kindly post your resources and comments bellow.
Any sample-codes/liraries/helper-classes links will be greatly appriciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you try to read the example.php and read all the php file in lib folder, I think you can achieve all these...

[example.php](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library/blob/master/example/example.php) has something like:

```
// orders
//print_r( $client->orders->get() );
//print_r( $client->orders->get( $order_id ) );
//print_r( $client->orders->update_status( $order_id, 'pending' ) );
```

and if you'll look at [class-wc-api-client-resource-orders.php](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library/blob/master/lib/woocommerce-api/resources/class-wc-api-client-resource-orders.php), you have this:

```
/**
 * Create an order
 *
 * POST /orders
 *
 * @since 2.0
 * @param array $data valid order data
 * @return array|object your newly-created order
 */
public function create( $data ) {
    $this->set_request_args( array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'body'   => $data,
    ) );
    return $this->do_request();
}
```

now you'll just have to test everything.

```
$orderData = array(
    "order" => array(
        "line_items" => array( 
            array(
                "product_id" => 1, 
                "quantity" => 1
            ) 
        )
    )
);

$client->orders->create($orderData);
```

---

Another suggestion is why not use [WooCommerce REST API](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) instead?
It has great documentation and examples.

Comment: Thanks Reigel! I thought it will be easier to implement the functions I need with a PHP wrapper library like this.

Answer (score 1):

$orderData = array(
    "order" => array(

```
/*

"set_paid"=>true

*/

"status"=>"processing",

"payment_details"=>array("method_id"=>"cod","method_title"=>"Cash on Delivery"),

"billing_address"=>array("first_name"=>"Tumusime","last_name"=>"Deus","company"=>"mcash",
"city"=>"Kampala","address_1"=>"Plot 7 Mukalazi zone","email"=>"jones@mcash.ug","phone"=>"0784529043",
),

"shipping_address"=>array("first_name"=>"Tumusime","last_name"=>"Deus","company"=>"mcash",
"city"=>"Kampala","address_1"=>"Plot 7 Mukalazi zone","email"=>"jones@mcash.ug","phone"=>"0784529043",
),
"shipping_lines"=>array(
array("id"=>5,"method_id"=>"flat_rate:1",
"method_title"=>"Flat rate","total"=>"10000.00")

),


    "line_items" => array( 
        array(
            "product_id" => 10, 
            "quantity" => 1,

        ) ,
         array(
            "product_id" => 15, 
            "quantity" => 2,

        ) 

    )
)
```

);

```
//$client->orders->create($orderData);

print_r($client->orders->create($orderData));
```